# CNContactPicker doesn't allow to select contacts

Tags: ios

```
   @IBAction private func addFriends(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let contactPicker  = CNContactPickerViewController()
        contactPicker.delegate = self

        setupDefualtAppearance()

        present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This is my CNContactPickerViewController call, and obvoiusly it doesn't work properly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJlwU.png)

Comment: delegate methods are not called ?

Comment: please describe what is not working exactly.

Comment: i cannot select contacts when contact picker vc appears. There's no such option. I have there delegate method (didSelect contacts), but the tricky thing about it is that it called only when i selected some contacts and pressed Done button at the top right of screen. But i can't either select contacts or press that button (cuz theres no such button). Mindblowing

Comment: Based on the image you provided, you would need to provide the code for the delegate to get a proper answer. But in either likely scenario, the presence of a delegate will disable the default behavior of displaying a secondary (child?) view with the CNContact. You have to do that yourself in the delegate's code.